# How can I have a new dropdown for each entity reference added?

Tags: entities

I have a content type with an entity reference to another content type that has over a hundred items. I want to use a dropdown menu to select the entity, since the user won't always know the titles of those entities. However, with so many entities, scrolling through and selecting multiple entities using the Select List widget is not the desired user experience.

Is there a way to make a new field appear per reference, like the autocomplete widget, but with dropdowns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into the [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) and/or [Select 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/select2) modules. They both work to improve UX for select fields.

I've used the Chosen module multiple times in the past, so that's where I'd lean here. The module improves the UX for users managing multiple selections on a select field. The chosen library alters the UI to allow users to easily select multiple options - it even provides autocomplete functionality to limit the results of the select field.

Comment: Chosen is perfect, thank you!